# Canonical 301 Redirect for Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If I have these dummy domain names `example1.com` and `example1.net` available. I want to redirect them as below using `.htaccess` file and `mod_rewrite` module:

```
example1.com -> www.example1.com
example1.net -> www.example1.com
www.example1.net -> www.example1.com
```

I have achieved the first task which is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example1\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example1\.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

What about the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it myself. Don't know how well the rules are written:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example1\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example1\.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example1\.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example1\.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.example1\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example1\.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Please correct or suggest a better answer